# move/drag an object on android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I am new to android and just learning android Canvas. I need to know how you can drag/move an object drawn on canvas in android. 
code snippet :

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

        eventX = event.getX(actionIndex);
        eventY = event.getY(actionIndex);


        final float dx = eventX - lastTouchX;
        final float dy = eventY - lastTouchY;

        stat_x += dx;
        stat_y += dy;

        lastTouchX = stat_x;
        lastTouchY = stat_y;

        invalidate();

        break;
    }
```

I found this kind of code somewhere but I need to know how to drag it. the object is moved to a new location with this code. What I need to achieve is dragging the object from one place to another. An example would be helpful and some detail regarding it would be appreciated. TIA